# Meaning Of "Don't you realize"

Tags: meaning

I heard this sentence a week ago but didn't get right. I told him that you are late to come. He told me, "Don't you realize-", then he stopped, turned and gone.  Someone please help me!

Comment: That's a lead-in to a sentence, the same as "please understand that..." or "aren't you aware that...".  What important is that they left out the important part of the sentence...what were you supposed to realize?  You might want to direct these questions to our sister site, English Language Learners because I notice that a lot of your questions are asking for the definition of common English terms.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Because i'm not a native english speaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Don't you realize" is a *turn of phrase* to indicate there's a reason behind the explanation to follow. Often it means that one should already know, or should have already guessed, what the reason is. Therefore using this phrase can be considered somewhat belittling, but ultimately it depends on the usage, tone of voice and the amount of sarcasm involved.

Without the remainder of the sentence that your acquaintance was going to say it's difficult to know how seriously they meant their comment.

Comment: yep!...and i like that in your mouth.